# Android Dark Mode: My menu text is black on dark gray, why is that so?

Tags: android, colors, menu, themes

Light mode is fine, Dark Mode is nearly not readable. The menu XML contains this (items reduced)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.petesTimer.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_MenuSetTime1"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menuEntrySetTime1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I tried changing the theme xml but it doesnt affect menu text color. Even if I take out black from theme completely and only have like red and blue, the text color for menu items remains black. Anyone an idea what to do ?

ps.: Also added this commonly suggested line to my themes:

```
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/my_menuTextColor</item>
```

But its doesnt take it, remains black.

Comment: Does this help you?  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme

Comment: you can disable dark mode for your app if you want.

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, I came across this already. And Thanks Danish, I really _want_ to support it :)

Answer (score 1):

in res/values/themes.xml in the section refered to by the android:theme section in your manifest file add

<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

for black text in daytime and in the res/values-night/themes.xml add

<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>

for white text at night.
P.S.  Just tried on a freshly created app with minSdk 19 and targetSdk 32 on an android 10 device.  Didn't try @color... however.